# Trouble with CSS in rails forms

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to set up my rails forms to have `border-box` using the following CSS. But it doesn't seem like the css is being applied to my fields and I am not sure why.

Note: I recently updated my app from Bootstrap 2.3 to Bootstrap 3.1. Not sure if this has any effect but I thought it was worth mentioning.

**View**

```
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :website %>
  <%= f.text_field :website %>

  <%= f.label :primary_field %>
  <%= f.select :primary_field, @primary_field %>

  <%= f.label :address %>
  <%= f.text_field :address, :placeholder => '123 Test St, City State Zip'%>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, :size => "30x5" %>

  <%= f.submit "Add Company", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

**CSS.SCSS File**

```
@mixin box-sizing($box-model) {
  -webkit-box-sizing: $box-model; // Safari <= 5
     -moz-box-sizing: $box-model; // Firefox <= 19
          box-sizing: $box-model;
}

....

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input, {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
```

**Picture of the output** These boxes should be bigger
[image]

Comment: Is your CSS being loaded after any other vendor CSS?

Comment: I don't think so, all my css in is just in the custom.css.scss file that rails generates. Everything was working fine until I upgraded my bootstrap, now I am having trouble getting the padding on all these to work properly

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are changes you need to change in your CSS to make it work as before. Found this Migration guide from Bootstrap 2.x to 3.x. Try follow this [guide](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide).

Comment: Ill take a dive into this when I get the chance later today, but at first glance, it looks really good!